# Write into file without overwriting

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-fs

Here we have a function of file read and write. we want to add data in the existing file withput overwriting but this is overwriting data in text file even after using `a` flag.

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.writeFileSync("sample.txt",'Y',"UTF-8",{'flags':'a'})
fs.readFile("sample.txt",(err,data) => {
    if(err){
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log("Data read : ",data.toString())
})
```

Comment: You're passing too many parameters; `writeFileSync` takes three params. Encoding is also an option. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options

Comment: *(More accurately: if you need multiple options encoding is an option, not a string.)*

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that you are using writeFileSync instead of appendFileSync

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.appendFileSync("sample.txt", 'Y', "UTF-8");
fs.readFile("sample.txt",(err,data) => {
    if(err){
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log("Data read : ",data.toString())
})
```

Using the flags option with writeFileSync is not needed in this case because you are only writing a single character to the file. appendFileSync will add the character to the end of the file without overwriting any existing data.

Comment: I'd say the issue with the **code** is that it's just wrong, although I agree `appendFileSync` is a more-communicative solution.